# Calling RegOpenCurrentUser in VC++ 6

Tags: visual-c++, winapi

I'm working on a Visual C++ 8 project on WinXP but 
unfortunately I have only Visual C++ 6.0 available.
When compiling it,an error is raised:
"error C2065: 'RegOpenCurrentUser' : undeclared identifier".
Since `RegOpenCurrentUser` has been introduced as late as Windows 2000,it's not included in VC6 header files.I try to declare it myself and add `#pragma comment(lib, "C:\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v6.0A\\Lib\\Advapi32.lib")` to the source code,but it doesn't work.
How can I call it or is there any equivalent function?

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to get Microsoft Visual Studio Express?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [RegOpenKey(Ex)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724895(VS.85).aspx) with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`.  This is fine so long as your app does not impersonate other users.